# Etymology of '하염없이' - was there ever such a thing as a '하염'?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

하염하염없이 is translated by naver dic as **blankly, vacantly**:

> 그는 하염없이 벽만 바라보았다 -
>   He stared blankly at the wall.

or **ceaselessly**:

> 하염없이 걷다 -
>   walk endlessly

A formation of *X-없이* would normally suggest that X would be a noun with some particular meaning, but there doesn't seem to be such a thing as a '하염'. Was there ever? if not, what's the origin of the word 하염없이?

Comment: possibly an archaic word involving the syllable 염/념 from the Chinese character 念 meaning thought...하 has a number of possibilities including "stream" ....without a stream of thought?  Just a guess but it kind of makes sense to me.

Comment: @B.Alvn If it's a hanja word, it's more likely 何念 "any thought".

Comment: that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly a reputable source, but [here](http://m.tip.daum.net/question/3768663) is some information on the etymology of the phrase "하염없이". @Mujjigun is right with the hanja - according to the source, 하염 comes from 何念(어찌할 하, 생각 념), which means 어찌할 생각 = 어떠한 생각. Therefore, 하염없이 would mean 어찌한 생각도 없이 = vacantly.

A similar phrase (but not interchangeable) is 정처 없이, which means "without a set destination." In this example, 정처 means "정해진 장소 (定處).